# Code Size for stack, accumulator, register-memory, memory-memory

Tags: assembly, stack, cpu-architecture

> For the following assume that values A, B, C, D, E, and F reside in
> memory. Also assume that instruction operation codes are represented
> in 5 bits, memory addresses are 64 bits, data size is 32 bits and
> register addresses are 4 bits.
>
> a. For each instruction set architecture shown in Figure A.2, how many
> addresses, or names (including both memory and register), appear in
> each instruction for the code to compute C = A+B, and what is the
> total code size?
>
> b. Some of the instruction set architectures in Figure A.2 destroy
> operands in the course of computation. This loss of data values from
> processor internal storage has performance consequences. For each
> architecture in Figure A.2, write the code sequence to compute:
> `C = A + B`, `D = B + F`, and `E = C + D`.
> In your code, mark each operand that is
> destroyed during execution and mark each “overhead” instruction that
> is included just to overcome this loss of data from processor internal
> storage. What is the total code size, the number of bytes of
> instructions and data moved to or from memory, the number of overhead
> instructions, and the number of overhead data bytes for each of your
> code sequences?
>
> [image: Figure A.2]

I tried answering for a, but I can not be able to calculate the code size for each.

Comment: What difficulty did you run into when attempting it?  Like whether to round up the instruction size to a whole number of bytes (multiple of 8 bits)?  It doesn't say to do so, so perhaps we're supposed to assume the instruction format is a bitstream, so they want to look at the theoretical minimum number of bits, not a more conventional design.  (Using 64-bit absolute memory addresses is also unusual for real-world 64-bit designs; for example x86-64 has PC-relative addressing with a 32-bit offset from the program counter for addressing static data.)

Comment: In part b, I'd wonder whether you can `push` (no operand) to duplicate something on the top of the stack, instead of having to `push B` twice, or to avoid reloading `C` from memory after calculating it.  (`push` / `pop C` to save it for later as well as store, instead of `pop C` / `push C`.)  But part a seems straightforward to me, so you'll have to go into detail about your attempt and what you need more explanation of.  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Each instruction has 5 bits for an opcode, and more bits for each operand.  It tells you how many bits are needed for each type of operand.

Comment: Correct me here, I came up with the solution for code size for stack is 28 bytes?

Comment: I'm not sure how to calculate it to be honest. As @PeterCordes said it's very unusual for real-world hardware to use a full 64-bit address for memory. Usually, immediate constants and memory addresses are compressed using bit rotation and PC-relative addressing, respectively. With x86 as the exception to the norm, it's very common for most CPUs to use a fixed size (typically 4 bytes) for every instruction to simplify the execution process. That is, every "line" would be 4 bytes at a minimum, regardless of whether or not all of that space is actually needed.

Comment: @puppydrum64: encoding immediates using a rotate count is not common.  ARM / AArch64 does it, but I don't know of another ISA that does that.  Usually with RISCs `lui` + `addi` or similar can generate an arbitrary 32-bit constant.

Comment: @PeterCordes Fair point, ARM is the only one I could think of at the time. I should have said instead, that it's typically limited and must be done in steps.